# How to include .filter function in my data filtering component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I got my data fetched, but I need to filter them based on the letter they include (typical live search), but I am not sure how and where to include the function

I am thinking the function would look something like this:

```
this.filteredResults = res.results.filter(filteredResults =>
              filteredResults.toLowerCase().includes(this.result.toLowerCase())
            );
```

And this is my data fetch using axios

```
 methods: {
    onChange() {
      axios
        .get("myURL")
        .then((response) => {
          this.filteredResults = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errors = true;
        })
        .finally(() => console.log("Data successfully loaded"));
      this.filterResults();
      this.modal = true;
    },
    
filterResults() {
          this.filteredResults = this.results.filter((result) => {
            return result.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
          });
        },

    setResult(filteredResult) {
      this.search = filteredResult;
      this.modal = false;
    },
  },

  watch: {
    results: function(val, oldValue) {
      if (val.length !== oldValue.length) {
        this.filteredResults = val;
      }
    },
  },
```

**Current output is showing whole list of data when start typing, but filtering does not work what so ever - no errors anywhere detected, when some item is clicked this is output in input (see image)**

[image: example input]

What is the right way to use .filter in Vue?

Answer (score 0):

```
methods: {
    onChange() {
      axios
        .get("myURL")
        .then((response) => {
        this.filteredresults=FilterOnInput((response.data,document.getelementById("IdOfTheInput").value)

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errors = true;
        })
        .finally(() => console.log("Data successfully loaded"));
      this.modal = true;
    },
    
//new !!
  FilterOnInput(list, inputFilter) {
  let filteredList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    let name = list[i].Name; //if given returns are objects 
    if (name.toUpperCase().includes(inputFilter.toUpperCase())) {
      filteredList.push(list[i]);
    }
  }
  if (inputFilter.length === 0) {
    filteredList = list;
  }
  return filteredList;
}
```

This getelementById("IdOfTheInput").value is only needed when working with id if you use a v-model, just put the name of the variable you use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but isnt there a simplier method how to implement it? I am just trying to learn Vue and want to know the basic functions before I'll dig into it and find other solutions

Comment: the awnser of omerS works the same, just not using the store getter, u can use the store in the computed instead of the "methods" doesn't really matters how you do it. i just showed you the "vuex" way of using store and his possibilities :)

Comment: Sure, I appreciate it :) I used `computed: {
    filtered() {
      return this.results.filter((filteredResults) =>
        filteredResults.toLowerCase().includes(this.result.toLowerCase())
      );
    },
  },` but unfortunately it still not working, is it used right ?

Comment: [here is sandbox link @tony19 (https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-architecture-91tj6?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:943-971)

Comment: i will edit my response so that you have a good awnser gimmi a sec